# Single cell checklist in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

This should be extremely simple, but I'm finding so little about it online that I'm beginning to sadly think it might not be possible. All I want is to create a checklist in google sheets, the same way you can in virtually any word processing program, and have it live in a single cell and have the values be easily customized. Instead, what I'm seeing mostly is a single checkbox per cell. Is there any way to do this, or am I kind of screwed?

Example of what I'd like to accomplish, inside a single cell, preferably in a simple fashion (this ultimately is going to be used to track QA tasks for designers, so the less technical, the better, short of initial setup which will be handled by me).

- [x] <strike>Item 1</strike>
- [ ] Item 2
- [ ] Item 3

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In your goal, you want to put the checkbox and text in only one cell, and want to manually control the checkbox. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes that's correct.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 2):

having multiple fully functional checkboxes per one single cell is not possible. you will either need to give up on functionality (ability to check it and uncheck it on a whim) or the whole idea. fake checkboxes are of course possible with a script or even internal formula.

Comment: Even though it's not what I want to hear, my gut is telling me that this is likely the only real answer. Obviously the ability to check and uncheck the checkboxes is fundamental to a checklist, although if you have any resources you can point me to in regards to faking it, I'd at least be interested to study it and see if I can repurpose it somehow into something that can work for my intended purpose.

Comment: @tganyan see: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/118881/186471

Answer (score 0):

### Simple, nontechnical

> Change the cell left border color to white.

[image]